# Using the %>% in R - specific case

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use the pipe function from the dplyr package in R to rewrite this chunk of code:

```
library(dplyr)

parking_information <- restaurant_information 
parking_information <- parking_information[!parking_information$PlaceID 
                                       %in% payment$PlaceID, ]
parking_information <- parking_information[-which(is.na
             (as.numeric(parking_information$Parking_Lot))), ]
```

What I am trying to do is this:

```
parking_information <- restaurant_information %>%
[!parking_information$PlaceID %in% payment$PlaceID, ] %>%
[-which(is.na(as.numeric(parking_information$Parking_Lot))), ]
```

However, this is generating an error and it is underlying the [] brackets. It doesn't look OK indeed but I do not really know how to make it work. Your advice will be appreciated!

Comment: data wld be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

parking_information <- restaurant_information %>%
    filter(!(PlaceID %in% payment$PlaceID), 
           !is.na(as.numeric(Parking_Lot)))
```

and if you'd like to get the most of `%>%`

```
library(dplyr)

parking_information <- restaurant_information %>%
    filter(!(PlaceID %in% payment$PlaceID), 
           !(Parking_Lot %>% as.numeric() %>% is.na()))
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Out of curiosity - what is this magrittr package doing? Why would it increase the efficiency of %>%?

Comment: Yeah, I'm also confused by your loading of magrittr, when it seems that dplyr gets everything you need for your code here.

Comment: Glad I could help. Here seems to add no value. I'm just accustomed to add `magrittr` when there'll be vector piping for the other operators. Thanks.

Comment: I see, but generally, you mean that to make %>% work, we always have to put some sort of function in front of the piped information, am I right? I am new to R so sorry for these basic questions.

Comment: Yes exactly. `%>%` takes what's on the left hand side (lhs) and puts it as the first argument in the function on the rhs

Comment: @Assen - http://rpubs.com/justmarkham/dplyr-tutorial this a `dplyr` tutorial if you're interested

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `.` needed to operate on `parking_information`. See the [magrittr documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html).

```
parking_information <- restaurant_information %>%
.[!parking_information$PlaceID %in% payment$PlaceID, ] %>%
.[-which(is.na(as.numeric(parking_information$Parking_Lot))), ]
```

Comment: The problem is that now it is deleting all my variables and leaves the columns only.When I initially tried it, it did work, but when I tried again later on, it said -
Error: object 'parking_information' not found

Comment: @Assen when you try it and it works, and then your try it later and it doesn't work, it means that you weren't starting in the same place.